# Can anyone please help/tell me what I am doing wrong? And/Or what I shouldve done in my queries?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have 3 models that I am using my query on:

**Models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
   ...

class SchoolPeriod(models.Model):
   period = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class StudentGrade(models.Model):
   student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
   period = models.ForeignKey(SchoolPeriod, ...)
   subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   grade = models.DecimalField(default = 75.00, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

class YearLevel(models.Model):
   year_level = models.CharField(...)
   school_level = models.CharField(...)

class Section(models.Model):
   year_level = models.OneToOneField(YearLevel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
   section = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   adviser = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank = True)

class Subject(models.Model):
   subject_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

**Views.py**

```
def viewgrade(request):
   current_parent = request.user.parent                              #gets current logged in parent
   tempstudent = Student.objects.get(parent = current_parent )       #gets student related to parent(theres no student user level)
   studentgrade = StudentGrade.objects.filter(student = tempstudent) #filters the grades of the student related to the parent logged in
   ...

   context = {
       ...
       'studentgrade': studentgrade,
   }
   return render(request, 'Information/viewgrade.html', context)
```

**viewgrade.html(template)**

```
<table style="width:50%">
 <tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
 </tr>
 {% for studentgrade in studentgrade %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{ studentgrade.subjects }}</td>
    <td>{{ studentgrade.grade }}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

What I can do was to print on my template the grades of the STUDENT that is related to the PARENT that is currently logged in.

But, I also want to arrange it per grading period(quarter)

*example:*

```
**first grading**
Science = 99
Math = 99

**second grading**
Science = 70
Match = 70
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if there are multiple `Student`s with the same `parent`?

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your models.py file,i think that u have to loop through the subjects like {{for subject in  studentgrade.subjects.objects.all}} because it's returning a queryset

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then I would've had a problem, Thanks! maybe I should change it to getlist?

Comment: @MohcenCH Will do, I'll add my entire model.py

Comment: I am still stuck here, can someone help?